# A dog, its owner, and the other person

Tags: mathematics

2 people, A and B, are 300 meters away from each other and are walking towards each other in a straight line at 1 meter per second. A has a dog that can run at 2 meter per second. The dog runs in a straight line towards person B, and as soon as it reaches B, instantly starts running towards A and repeats it until A and B meet.

How many times does the dog turn?

This is a forward from a WhatsApp group chat with no further attribution.

Comment: Surely the dog will turn an infinite number of times as the distance it travels between turns goes to zero?

Comment: I think you can stop counting turns when it becomes apparent the dog is chasing its own tail.

Comment: Usualy asked about the distance dog runs.: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993646/john-von-neumann-exercise-about-a-fly-and-two-trains

Comment: It should be about 4 - 6 turns, if we can stop counting, when the dog is already chasing it's own tail

Comment: Even if this isn't a homework problem, since you didn't make it yourself, could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) to the creator? It's a site requirement so that puzzle-makers get credit.

Comment: @bobble, well a friend asked this on a whatsapp group chat and it was a fwd text. Everyone promptly ignored it and moved on so I'm not sure who created it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the dog is not an a-dimensional point, let's consider it has a length. Let's assume is 1 meter which is the average length of an adult German Shepard. I like German Shepards.
So this means "the game" stops when the distance between the 2 people goes below 1 meter.
In this case, the dog will turn ....

> 5 times. and makes 6 runs.

Reasoning

> The dog will reach B when B has walked 100 meters and the dog 200. This will be turn 1.
>  In the mean time A walked 100 meters. This means the distance between A and B is now 100 meters (300 - 100 - 100).
>  Now we have the same situation (symmetrical) but with the distance of only 100 meters. between A and B. So it is 1 third of the initial distance.
>  Going further, when the dog reaches A, the distance between A and be has become 1 third of 100 so 33.33.

So the results.

> Here are the distances between A and B after each dog turn.
>  100 (turn 1)
>  33.33 (turn 2)
>  11.11 (turn 3)
>  3.7 (turn 4)
>  1.22 (turn 5)
>  0.4  - we've reached the stop condition.  (dog might be crushed here)

Disclaimer: No animals were hurt in the process of writing this answer.

Comment: my dog is a puppy of a small breed and can make 2 more turns! (0.1333 and then 0.04444) Bigger isn't always better :D

Comment: I did not claim that. All I said is that I like German Shepards.

Comment: So, I was right with my claim (see my comment on the *question*)

Comment: I had a german shepherd growing up and they're my favourite dogs too! So I'm marking this as the answer :D

Answer (score 6):

Every time the dog turns, it starts running towards the other person. It reaches the other person before the person it has just left does, because it is faster. So when it reaches the other person, A and B have not yet met, meaning that it turns again. Thus there is no last turn, and there is clearly a first turn, so it turns infinitely many times.

Comment: now all wee need to do is harness the infinite kinetic energy from the dog

Comment: And we have infinite kinetic energy, and become the next iron man!

Comment: @WOWOW. Right. I'll start working on the suit.

Comment: I will create my spider-man suit

Comment: We'll see who is stronger...